# Vim script capture number user inputs in response to "Type number and <Enter> (empty cancels):"

Tags: function, vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

For example if a user is trying to jump to a tag and uses the following command:

```
:tjump "some_function"
```

Vim will show a list of possible tag matches. Is there a way to 'capture' what the user inputted?

Example in a function:

```
function! GoToTag ()
    let l:search_tag = expand('<cword>')     " this will capture the word under the cursor
    exe 'tjump' l:search_tag
    """" capture the number the user puts in
```

My goal is to be able to jump to a file that the user chooses but if it doesn't exist, check out that file from a repository and then go to it. Going to the file automatically after checking it out without requesting that the user input that number again is proving to be difficult:

```
function! GoToTag ()
    try
        let l:search_tag = expand('<cword>')    " Get the word under the cursor
        exe 'tjump' l:search_tag                " go to tag, list options if tag is in multiple locations
    catch /^Vim(tjump):E429:/                   " catch the missing file error if file doesn't exist (not synced)
        """ sync the file the user wanted to jump to using whatever repository command applies to you
        """ go to that file and line corresponding to the user's original choice
    entry
endfunction
```

Comment: Please give more background; what is your final goal? When a question is only about a small technical step, it's difficult to provide a good answer. If you don't tell us **why** you want this, it's easy to succumb to the [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @IngoKarkat I updated the original question to provide my ultimate goal. I basically have a tags file that indexes my codebase and I want to selectively check out files that I want to look at without checking out the entire codebase.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only observe the effect (of jumping to a tag), or abort the user selection, capture the output, and re-implement the echoing and querying yourself, e.g.:

```
let search_tag = expand('<cword>')
redir => commandOutput
    silent! execute 'tjump' search_tag
redir END
echo substitute(commandOutput, '\n[^\n]*$', '', '') " Remove last query line; we'll duplicate that with input().
let answer = input('Type number and <Enter>: ')
```